# Why does CSS "blur" backdrop-filter not work in Chrome?

Tags: css

In CSS, I use the `backdrop-filter` property to blur the background of the sticky header.

Therefore, I used `backdrop-filer:blur(10px)` and set `opacity:50%`.

If you run the code, the sticky header background will not blur. Can you tell me why the sample code doesn't work?

```css
.sticky{
    background-color:orangered;
    opacity: 50%;
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);


    position: sticky;
    top:0;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
 
  <body>
   
      <div class="sticky">
        <h1>This is a header</h1>
      </div>
   

      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam
        asperiores at autem, dicta dignissimos ex, fugiat fugit harum id itaque
        nulla odio perferendis quasi qui similique! Doloribus nesciunt quaerat
        tempora.

      </p>
      <div style="height: 400px"></div>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam
        asperiores at autem, dicta dignissimos ex, fugiat fugit harum id itaque
        nulla odio perferendis quasi qui similique! Doloribus nesciunt quaerat
        tempora.
      </p>
      <div style="height: 400px"></div>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam
            asperiores at autem, dicta dignissimos ex, fugiat fugit harum id itaque
            nulla odio perferendis quasi qui similique! Doloribus nesciunt quaerat
            tempora.

        </p>
        <div style="height: 400px"></div>
    
  </body>
```

Comment: Check if you have the Latest Chrome Version ( greater than 75 )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Chrome does support `backdrop-filter`. https://caniuse.com/?search=backdrop-filter.
2. `backdrop-filter` only works in conjunction with `background-color` if the background colour has transparency.
3. You cannot see a blur effect if there is no background to blur. A blurred solid colour would look exactly the same!
4. I also recommend removing opacity.

---

If you want to change the background color, try using:

- backdrop-filter: sepia(.8);
- backdrop-filter: hue-rotate(30deg);

to get the desired efffect.

```css
body {
  background: url(https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fimages8.alphacoders.com%2F992%2F992848.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
}

@supports ((-webkit-backdrop-filter: none) or (backdrop-filter: none)) {
  .sticky {
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    height: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="sticky">
    <h1>This is a header</h1>
  </div>

  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam asperiores at autem, dicta dignissimos ex, fugiat fugit harum id itaque nulla odio perferendis quasi qui similique! Doloribus nesciunt quaerat tempora.

  </p>
  <div style="height: 400px"></div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam asperiores at autem, dicta dignissimos ex, fugiat fugit harum id itaque nulla odio perferendis quasi qui similique! Doloribus nesciunt quaerat tempora.
  </p>
  <div style="height: 400px"></div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam asperiores at autem, dicta dignissimos ex, fugiat fugit harum id itaque nulla odio perferendis quasi qui similique! Doloribus nesciunt quaerat tempora.

  </p>
  <div style="height: 400px"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Backdrop-filter does work with background color, it just has to be semi-transparent for the effect to be visible. There are some examples of background color with backdrop filter on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter#examples

Comment: @KawaLo thank you bringing this to my attention. I have updated the answer.

Comment: very helpful, thanks my king =)

Answer (score 0):

Try directly state opacity using RGB**A** in the `background-color`, it will work:

```css
.sticky{
    background-color:rgba(255,69,0,0.5); //orangered = rgb(255,69,0)
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px); //mobile-friendly


    position: sticky;
    top:0;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
   
      <div class="sticky">
        <h1>This is a header</h1>
      </div>
   

      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam
        asperiores at autem, dicta dignissimos ex, fugiat fugit harum id itaque
        nulla odio perferendis quasi qui similique! Doloribus nesciunt quaerat
        tempora.

      </p>
      <div style="height: 400px"></div>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam
        asperiores at autem, dicta dignissimos ex, fugiat fugit harum id itaque
        nulla odio perferendis quasi qui similique! Doloribus nesciunt quaerat
        tempora.
      </p>
      <div style="height: 400px"></div>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam
            asperiores at autem, dicta dignissimos ex, fugiat fugit harum id itaque
            nulla odio perferendis quasi qui similique! Doloribus nesciunt quaerat
            tempora.

        </p>
        <div style="height: 400px"></div>
    
  </body>
```

Answer (score -2):

> background-filter does not work in conjunction with background-color.

```
.sticky{
background-color:#3ea66263;
backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
position: sticky;
top:0;
height: 100px;
}
```

Works well for me. Did I miss something ?

Comment: this is not an answer but rather a comment.

Comment: @MehrdadDastgir Well I'm sorry, this may not be a complete answer for you but it's definitely not a comment since I am providing : the answer that answers the user's problem (code). At the same time I point out that what I propose contradicts the best answer given (a fact that I found interesting) so I say it works well for me despite the fact that the opposite has been said before and I try to be polite asking if I missed something. Which part of my answer is a comment for you? The answer, the interesting fact or the politeness?